# update command not working in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlcommand

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter myadp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myadp.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("Update [orgs] Set [fname]=@fname,[weblnk]=@weblnk,[email]=@email,[cntct]=@cntct,[lctn]=@lctn,[cdscrptn]=@cdscrptn,[bsnstp]=@bsnstp WHERE [cmpny]=" +Label1.Text,mycon);
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@weblnk", SqlDbType.VarChar,80).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar,80).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@cntct", SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@lctn", SqlDbType.VarChar,80).Value = TextBox6.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@cdscrptn", SqlDbType.VarChar,600).Value = TextBox7.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@bsnstp", SqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value = TextBox8.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Connection = mycon;
        mycon.Open();
        myadp.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mycon.Close();
    }
```

---

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter myadp = new SqlDataAdapter();
        myadp.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("Update [orgs] Set [fname]=@fname,[weblnk]=@weblnk,[email]=@email,[cntct]=@cntct,[lctn]=@lctn,[cdscrptn]=@cdscrptn,[bsnstp]=@bsnstp WHERE [cmpny]=@cmpny", mycon);
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@cmpny", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox2.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@weblnk", SqlDbType.VarChar,80).Value = TextBox3.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar,80).Value = TextBox4.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@cntct", SqlDbType.VarChar,20).Value = TextBox5.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@lctn", SqlDbType.VarChar,80).Value = TextBox6.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@cdscrptn", SqlDbType.VarChar,600).Value = TextBox7.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@bsnstp", SqlDbType.VarChar,40).Value = TextBox8.Text;
        myadp.UpdateCommand.Connection = mycon;
        mycon.Open();
        myadp.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        mycon.Close();
    }
```

here I have parametrize `cmpny` too but its still not working

Comment: Any error or exception?

Comment: You should parameterize `cmpny` as well.

Comment: Not working? Did you get any exception?

Comment: describle more what error you are facing... we can't help you without explanation

Comment: Mansfield is right. You have not set cmpny parameter.

Comment: You are connecting to the master Database? Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: i got this Invalid column name 'dsacsd'.

Comment: And what's the use of the SqlDataAdapter here?

Comment: how can i set cmpny parameter

Comment: The same way you did with the other parameters

Comment: i have tried that already ,it is not working that way either

Comment: Your code does not do anything with the data you insert; what makes you think it is "not working"?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that `cmpny` is a text field, so you need to enclose it in apostrophes:

```
WHERE [cmpny]='" + Label1.Text + "'",mycon);
```

However, forget this immediately. You should use parameters **always**.

```
WHERE [cmpny]=@cmpny", mycon);
```

and

```
myadp.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cmpny", TextBox1.Text);
```

Comment: this one is not working too

Comment: @GiteshSawariya: Do you have more details? Do you get an exception on `mycon.Open();`? Use the debugger.

Comment: no i am not getting any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get rid of the unnecessary SqlDataAdapter.
2. Get a real Database on your local server. The master database isn't intended for your data.
3. Check the return value of ExecuteNonQuery. Maybe your assumed cmpny value doesn't exist in the table?
4. Attach a minimum of Exception Handling to your code.

```
using (SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    mycon.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update [orgs] Set [fname]=@fname,[weblnk]=@weblnk,[email]=@email,[cntct]=@cntct,[lctn]=@lctn,[cdscrptn]=@cdscrptn,[bsnstp]=@bsnstp WHERE [cmpny]=@cmpny", mycon))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text;
        // all the other params
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bsnstp", SqlDbType.VarChar, 40).Value = TextBox8.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@cmpny", /*correct Datatype here*/).Value = Label1.Text;  // from a Label ?? how does it got there? You should take the value from the actual source
        int affectedRecords = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: this one is not working too..

Comment: i have tried them all. I am not getting any exceptions or errors, but it is not updating

Comment: Have you checked the return of ExecuteNonQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Label1.Text should be parameterized too because it may contains some quotes.
In a general way, you should parametize every user inputed value in SQL in order to avoid SQL injections.

You may have some error because of this so your update command is not working.